# flutter_localizations and intl in all pages flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to implement flutter_localizations and intl in all pages? Otherwise I will get this error for my next page:-

No instance of S present in the widget tree. Did you add S.delegate in localizationsDelegates?
'package:dice/generated/l10n.dart':
Failed assertion: line 44 pos 12: 'instance != null'